# Difficulties compiling OpenCV on Ubuntu ARM

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, compilation, arm, gnu

I'm trying to compile OpenCV to use it on a ODROID-UX3 machine (ARM architecture) with Ubuntu 14.04. Following the guide on the OpenCV website I'm trying to install the cross compilation tools (gnueabihf) with no luck. Apt-get doesn't seem to locate the package **gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf**. Is there a compatibility issue?

Comment: Between the title and the question itself it's not clear exactly what you're building on. If it's the Odroid itself then you can ignore anything to do with cross-compiling because you're just building natively.

Comment: Yes I'm building it natively. Can I compile it using only the gcc?

Comment: That's generally how building natively works, yes. If you have a real urge to explicitly specify the target system you might already be able to - the Ubuntu 14.04 x86 box I'm on certainly has the symlink `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-4.8` ;)

Comment: Thank you! There was no point cross compiling, I just built it natively.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ubuntu has a package named gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

[here:](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/devel/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf)

> Package: gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf (4:4.6.2-7) [universe] 
>   The GNU C compiler for armhf architecture

Your problem is something else.